# Reg ex - find a string without certain characters

Tags: regex, textmate

Using regex, how do I search for a string that does not include cetrain characters?

If I'm searching through directory in textmate for the string 'flash/' I'd like to exclude the result  'flash/navigation'

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative look ahead:

```
/flash\/(?!navigation)/
```